# What's the meaning of "emotional stake"?

Tags: meaning, figures-of-speech, figurative

What does an "emotional stake" mean?

E.g: to increase the emotional stakes, I had my favorites in both.

Comment: Are you aware of the meaning of the word [stake](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stake?q=stake#stake-2)?

Answer (score 1):

Emotional stake means you had a particular emotional interest in the outcome, perhaps if your children were playing against each other on different teams. This would tie in with your example. A sibling rivalry would be the perfect example of competing emotional stakes.

Answer (score 0):

Emotional sake is something which bounds a person to perform some action, just to give respect or for the sake of that particular emotion with which its attached.

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Comment: You've misread the question.